# Transform a sequence of discontinuous intervals into continuous

Tags: r

I have data that looks like (simplified)

```
chr start end sv
A  4   6   DEL
A  10  15  DEL
B  8   18  INS
B  20  22  DEL
B  23  24  DEL
C  1   2   DEL
C  3   4   INS
C  7   8   INS
C  12  16  DEL
C  20  30  DEL
```

I would like to delete the gaps between the intervals, for each element in the first column, while keeping the interval size

```
chr start end sv
A  1   3   DEL
A  4   9   DEL
B  1   11  INS
B  12  14  DEL
B  15  16  DEL
C  1   2   DEL
C  3   4   INS
C  5   6   INS
C  7   11  DEL
C  12  22  DEL
```

I wanna do this bc I think this might be the solution to delete the gaps in this plot

```
d2 <- fread("sv.nc.nobnd.tab", header = TRUE)
# Compute chromosome size
don1 <- group_by(d2, chr) #%>% 
don2 <- summarise(don1, chr_len=max(end)) #%>% 
# Calculate cumulative position of each chromosome
don2$tot <- cumsum(as.numeric(don2$chr_len))
don4 <- select(don2, -chr_len) #%>%
# Add this info to the initial dataset
don5 <- left_join(d2, don4, by=c("chr"="chr")) #%>%
# Add a cumulative position of each SNP
don7 <- mutate(don5, startPos=start+tot, finalPos=end+tot)
axisdf = don7 %>% group_by(chr) %>% summarize(center=( max(finalPos) + min(finalPos) ) / 2 )

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = don7, aes(xmin = startPos, xmax = finalPos, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill=sv)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=axisdf$center, labels=axisdf$chr, guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))+
  theme_bw() +
  theme( 
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=20),
  )
```

[image]

But I'm not sure this is the right route, and have tried all sorts of unsuccessful mutating of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate `sequence`s and their `range` out of the differences in a split/combine approach using `by`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$chr, function(x) {
  m <- as.matrix(x[2:3])
  m <- m - m[1, 1] + 1
  sq <- m[,2] - m[,1] + 1
  x[2:3] <- t(sapply(Map(`+`, sapply(sq, sequence), 
                         c(0, cumsum(sq)[-length(sq)])), range))
  x
}))
res
#      chr start end  sv
# A.1    A     1   3 DEL
# A.2    A     4   9 DEL
# B.3    B     1  11 INS
# B.4    B    12  14 DEL
# B.5    B    15  16 DEL
# C.6    C     1   2 DEL
# C.7    C     3   4 INS
# C.8    C     5   6 INS
# C.9    C     7  11 DEL
# C.10   C    12  22 DEL
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(chr = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), start = c(4L, 10L, 8L, 20L, 23L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 12L, 
20L), end = c(6L, 15L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 30L), 
    sv = c("DEL", "DEL", "INS", "DEL", "DEL", "DEL", "INS", "INS", 
    "DEL", "DEL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```